# mongodb/node: Pushing a new value to mongodb and displaying it

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a field in my User model
`courseId: { type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId] },`

I am adding info in my database in 4 steps. On the fourth step, along with the final info, i want the id of the info to be pushed in this courseId field. The Express route is defined like this

```js
router.post('/course/:userid/step-four/:courseid', function(req, res) {
      Course.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.courseid, req.body, function(err, doc) {
            if (err) {
              res.send(err);
            } else {
              console.log("updated four");
              res.send(doc);
              User.update({_id: req.params.userid}, { $push{courseId: req.params.courseid}
              });
              console.log(User.courseId);
```

The problem is, i'm seeing `undefined` in my console and on mongo shell, the courseId field is not visible in the user document. Where is the error?

Comment: Schema.Types.ObjectId means  Field must object id.
Eg: _id of any document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, You have missed `:` after `$push` and don't send the response before updating record. convert userid to Mongo ObjectId and try.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

router.post('/course/:userid/step-four/:courseid', function (req, res) {
    Course.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.courseid, req.body, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            console.log("updated four");
            User.update({
                _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.userid);
            }, {
                $push: {
                    courseId: req.params.courseid
                }
            }, function (err, doc) {
                if (err) {
                    return res.send(err);
                }
                console.log("updated");
                return res.send(doc);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things I noticed off the bat that might help are 
 1. you're missing a colon after the `$push` and 
 2. With the `console.log(User.courseId);`, I'm assuming the `User` is the mongoose model, which is not the document, so it wouldn't contain any of the document's data.

Assuming your http request and mongoose models are formatted correctly, this code should work:

```
router.post('/course/:userid/step-four/:courseid', function(req, res) {
    Course.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.courseid, req.body, function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            console.log("updated four");
            res.send(doc);
            User.update({
                    _id: req.params.userid
                }, {
                    $push: {
                        courseId: req.params.courseid
                    }
                }, function(err, result) {
                    User.findById(req.params.userid, function(err, doc) {
                        console.log("updated courseId", doc.courseId);
                    });
            });
            console.log("bad courseId", User.courseId);
        }
    })
```